# Scale animation imageview on touch event?

Tags: android, animation, imageview

i want make a scale animation on imageview, when i touch on display.
there's a problem: when i touch the imageview go to the origin point or if i set pivot to 50%, imageview scale to the center.
why?
i tried this code:

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent e) 
{

    float x = e.getX();
    float y = e.getY();

   ImageView image= new ImageView(context);
image.setx = x;
image.setY=y;
layout.addViews(image,300,300);
imageview.startAnimation(scaleAnimation);

    return true;
}
```